# GTK+ 3 applications based on .glade file on different OS

Tags: c++, gtk, gtk3, glade

I wrote small GTK+ application on C++ that works fine for me on Debian x64 with Gnome 3. However, it doesn't work on Lubuntu x86. So I've written test program that creates window with some widgets from my gui.glade file, and it doesn't work too on Lubuntu, but works on Debian. Here goes test code:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

void create_window()
{
    GtkBuilder *builder; 
    builder = gtk_builder_new();

    gtk_builder_add_from_file (builder, "src/gui.glade", NULL);
    gtk_builder_connect_signals (builder, NULL);

    GtkWidget *window;
    window = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "window"));

    gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Startup Settings");
    g_signal_connect (window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK (gtk_main_quit), NULL);

    gtk_widget_show (window);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);
    create_window();

    gtk_main ();
}
```

I compile it with g++:

```
g++ -std=c++11 `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` test.cpp -rdynamic `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0`
```

Error output:

```
** (a.out:17864): WARNING **: Error retrieving accessibility bus address: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.a11y.Bus was not provided by any .service files

(a.out:17864): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_window_set_title: assertion 'GTK_IS_WINDOW (window)' failed

(a.out:17864): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(a.out:17864): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

(a.out:17864): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_show: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' faile
```

You can download gui.glade [here](http://my-files.ru/Save/r2nen3/gui.glade).

Comment: Check your errors (last argument of `gtk_builder_add_from_file()`).

Comment: @andlabs, how to get an error message or code? An error occurs (`gtk_builder_add_from_file: assertion 'error == NULL || *error == null' failed`), but I can't do `g_print(error->message)`, it causes segmentation fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just opened my `gui.glade` file properties and the problem became obvious. By default Glade requires the latest version of GTK+ installed on your computer. I'm using Debian unstable, so for me it's GTK 3.20. When I tested it on stable system, it didn't work, because there was GTK 3.18 installed on it.

To solve the problem I've changed my `gui.glade` properties via Glage and decreased required GTK version to 3.10.